# Gauss-Bonnet Theorem in dimension four

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-topology, pfaffian

I've read that the generalized Gauss-Bonnet theorem states that

> $$\int\limits_{M}Pf(\Omega)=(2\pi)^n\chi(M)$$

where, $M$ is a 2n-dimensional compact orientable Riemannian manifold without boundary $\Omega$ is the curvature form and $Pf(\Omega)$ is the Pfaffian of $\Omega$, $Pf(\Omega)$ is a 2n-form.

How can I prove that in dimension four is valid:

> $$\chi(M)=\frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int\limits_M(|Rm|^2-4|Ric|^2+R^2)\,d\mu$$

where, $Rm$ is the Riemannian curvature tensor, $Ric$ is the Ricci curvature tensor ans $R$ is then scalar curvature.

Tahnks in advice.

Comment: Is just lifted straight from Wikipedia?

Comment: Maybe... But, do you have any idea to proof this? Thanks!

Comment: Can you please provide a hint how you did it ? How did you get the first term ? It would be very kind.

Comment: @user44690 See the answer that I've posted.

Answer (score 3):

Here some steps to achieve the solution:

1. Remember the curvature form $\Omega$ is a 2-form with values in $\mathfrak{o}(2n)$. If $(e_i)$ is a ortonormal basis and $(\theta^i)$ its dual, we have
   $$\Omega_i^j=\frac{1}{2}\theta^k\wedge\theta^lR_{kli}^j.$$
2. $$Pf(\Omega)=\frac{1}{2^nn!}\sum_{\sigma\in S_{2n}}{\rm sgn}\,(\sigma)\prod_{i=1}^n\Omega_{\sigma(2i-1)}^{\sigma(2i)}.$$
3. Check that, for $n=2$,
   $$Pf(\Omega)=\frac{1}{8}(|Rm|^2-4|Ric|^2+R^2).$$
4. Thus,
   $$\chi(M)=\frac{1}{32\pi^2}\int\limits_M(|Rm|^2-4|Ric|^2+R^2)\,d\mu
   $$

Comment: Dear Diego, Do you know any reference for (2)?

Comment: @C.F.G The definition of Pfaffian is for any skew-symmetric matrix, the determinant is the square of Pfaffian (Thomas Muir). Look here for the exact expression: http://scipp.ucsc.edu/~haber/webpage/pfaffian2.pdf

Comment: another reference is here: https://d31kydh6n6r5j5.cloudfront.net/uploads/sites/66/2019/04/pfaffian_comps_06_07.pdf