# How to efficiently compute this Pffafian of curvature form

Tags: differential-geometry

Though one can verify [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/500439/gauss-bonnet-theorem-in-dimension-four?rq=1)
$$Pf(\Omega) = \frac{1}{8}(\vert \text{Rm} \vert^2 - 4 \vert \text{Ric}\vert^2 + R^2)$$
for a 4-dim manifold by listing out all the curvature components mechanically (I have to ask my computer to do so), is there a clever way to compute this quantity? Thanks